# Android Widget, Intent on RemoteViews not fired in data present

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, intentfilter

In my AppWidgetProvider class, I'm programmatically adding some Button to the main layout through RemoteViews:

```
static void updateAppWidget(......) {
  ..
  RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main_widget);
  for (int i=0; i<maxViews, 4); ++i) {
    RemoteViews button = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_button);
    String number = numbers.get(i).getCode();

    // Test1
    Intent actionIntent = new Intent("MyIntent");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent, 0);
    button.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.image, pendingIntent);

    // Test2
    Intent actionIntent = new Intent("MyIntent");
    actionIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent, 0);
    button.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.image, pendingIntent);

    // Test3
    Intent actionIntent = new Intent("MyIntent");
    actionIntent.putExtra("number", number);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent, 0);
    button.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.image, pendingIntent);

    views.addView(R.id.content_layout, button);
  }
  ...
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  System.out.println("Action: "+intent.getAction());

  ...
}
```

Here the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".widget.EmergencyWidget" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    <action android:name="MyIntent" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
    android:resource="@xml/my_widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

Using the code in ***Test1***, when clicking on the button, the `onReceive` method is correctly fired.

Using the code in ***Test2***, when clicking on the button, the `onReceive` method is not fired.

Using the code in ***Test3***, when clicking on the button, the `onReceive` method fired but `intent.hasExtra("number")` returns false.

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test1 works because the action matches your Manifest, as you'd expect and the implicit intent is handled correctly.

Per [IntentFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html), if you declare both an action and data, then both need to match for the intent to match - as you do not declare a `<data>` element in your manifest, it will never match.

You could fix your Manifest by instead using:

```
<receiver android:name=".widget.EmergencyWidget" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    <action android:name="MyIntent" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="MyIntent" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
    android:resource="@xml/my_widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

Or by adding `setClassName(context, EmergencyWidget.class)` to your `Intent` - this would make it an explicit `Intent` and you wouldn't need to add anything to the Manifest (`<intent-filter>` is only used for implicit Intents where Android needs to figure out what component needs to be called).

Your Test3 runs into one optimization of android related to [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html): if two PendingIntents match another by [Intent.filterEquals](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)) then it will reuse the existing `PendingIntent` - extras are not considered on whether they are equal so the system probably has a PendingIntent without any extras which it is reusing (they are only cleared upon restarting your device). In this case, you can use

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

The [FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) tells Android to replace the extras when building the `PendingIntent`.